# loop in jQuery without using classes using Tumult Hype

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to put the following into a loop, but I'm not having much luck.

```
  $('#start_01_trigger').mouseover(function() {
    $('#start_01').css( "color", "#FFF" );
    $('#start_01_trigger').fadeTo("100", 0.4);
  });
  $('#start_01_trigger').mouseout(function() {
    $('#start_01').css( "color", "#68C3AD" );
    $('#start_01_trigger').fadeTo("100", 0);
  });
```

This is for a calendar app, so this would have to be iterated through 31 times.

The kicker is that I am using Tumult Hype to build this, and I cannot assign a class to elements. I can only assign ID's, and each one is unique.

That is the first iteration through the loop above, the 2nd would look like this:

```
  $('#start_02_trigger').mouseover(function() {
    $('#start_02').css( "color", "#FFF" );
    $('#start_02_trigger').fadeTo("100", 0.4);
  });
  $('#start_02_trigger').mouseout(function() {
    $('#start_02').css( "color", "#68C3AD" );
    $('#start_02_trigger').fadeTo("100", 0);
  });
```

You can see that just the number in the ID changed and nothing else.

Comment: Is the parent (or an ancestor) of these elements significantly individual enough to create a selector from there?

Comment: The parent element is an individual div with the id "start_date_menu".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute selectors to make a generic event handler:

```
$('div[id^="start_"][id$="_trigger"]').mouseover(function() {
    var $elem = $('#' + this.id.replace('_trigger', ''));

    $elem.css('color', 'red');
    $(this).fadeTo('100', 0);
});
```

- `[id^="start_"]` matches only if the `id` attribute starts with `start_`.
- `[id$="_trigger"]` matches only if the `id` attribute ends with `start_`.
- So in the end, it matches elements whose `id` attribute starts and ends with those two values.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. I was going to paste that original block of code out 31 times for each day of the month, but then thought there has to be shorter way to do this. I'm going to have to look up attribute selectors to make generic event handlers. I've never seen that before.